# HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando una aplicación con Angular en donde utilizo una httpclient.get pero me esta generando el siguiente error.

Espero me puedan ayudar a solucionar el problema.

GRacias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Imposible saber que dice el error. Cortaste las partes importantes. Edita tu pregunta para incluir el texto completo (no una foto).

Comment: hola disculpa, acabo de editar las images, creo que ya se muestra el error

Comment: Siyiyd, puedes intentar agregando el URL completo en el servicio?

Comment: si agrego el url al servicio me genera un error este error                        Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sjoaplprtg04/api/table.json?content=sensors&columns=objid,device,sensor,status,message&username=sbarboza&passhash=1138428550&output=json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: buscando encontre que debia crear un archivo pxy.conf.json el cual configure de la siguiente forma                                                                                                            {
    "/api/table.json": {
        "target": "https://sjoaplprtg04",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }

}